# How to print second/consecutive layer(s) of spiral order matrix

Tags: java, matrix

I'm trying to solve the Spiral order matrix problem (https://leetcode.com/problems/spiral-matrix-ii/description/)

I've cracked the problem (almost 97%). The code is failing in the second layer of printing. I'm posting my (Java) method (code that generates the matrix) here.

Any help is appreciated.

```
public int[][] generateMatrix(int inputNumber) {  
       int[][] spiralMatrix = new int[inputNumber][inputNumber];  
       int totalElementCount = inputNumber * inputNumber;   
       int topMostLeft = 0;   
       int bottomMostLeft = 0;  
       int topMostRight = inputNumber -1;  
       int bottomMostRight = inputNumber -1;  
       int row = 0;   
       int column = 0;   
       int direction = 1;   
       for(int loopIndex = 0; loopIndex < totalElementCount ; loopIndex++) {  
            //System.out.println("\nDirection : "+direction + " loopIndex : "+loopIndex);  
            //Left to right   
            if(direction == 1) {  
                 //System.out.println("row : " + row + " column : "+column + " topMostRight : "+topMostRight + " spiralMatrix[row][column] : "+spiralMatrix[row][column]);  
                 if(column < topMostRight) {  
                      if(spiralMatrix[row][column] == 0) {  
                           spiralMatrix[row][column++] = loopIndex+1;                                
                      }  
                      else {  
                           //System.out.println("Inside else");  
                           spiralMatrix[row][++column] = loopIndex+1;                                
                      }  
                      /*System.out.println("row : " + row + " column : "+column + " topMostRight : "+topMostRight);  
                      System.out.println("spiralMatrix[row][column++] :"+spiralMatrix[row][column]);*/  
                      //column++;  
                 }  
                 else if(column == topMostRight) {  
                      spiralMatrix[row][column] = loopIndex+1;       
                      topMostRight--;  
                      direction = 2;  
                 }  
            }  
            //Top to Bottom   
            if(direction == 2) {  
                 //System.out.println("row : "+row + " bottomMostRight : "+bottomMostRight);  
                 if(row < bottomMostRight) {  
                      spiralMatrix[row++][column] = loopIndex + 1;   
                 }  
                 else if(row == bottomMostRight) {  
                      spiralMatrix[row][column] = loopIndex+1;       
                      bottomMostRight--;  
                      direction = 3;  
                 }  
            }  
            //Right to left   
            if(direction == 3) {  
                 //System.out.println("column : "+column + " bottomMostLeft : "+bottomMostLeft);  
                 if(column > bottomMostLeft) {  
                      spiralMatrix[row][column--] = loopIndex + 1;  
                 }  
                 else if(column == bottomMostLeft) {  
                      spiralMatrix[row][column] = loopIndex+1;       
                      bottomMostLeft--;  
                      direction = 4;  
                 }  
            }  
            //Bottom to top  
            if(direction == 4) {  
                 //System.out.println("row : "+ row + " topMostLeft: "+topMostLeft);  
                 if(row > topMostLeft) {  
                      spiralMatrix[row--][column] = loopIndex+1;  
                 }  
                 else if (row == topMostLeft) {  
                      topMostLeft++;  
                      column++;  
                      row++;  
                      direction = 1;  
                      //System.out.println("row : "+row + " column : "+column + " loopIndex : "+loopIndex);  
                      spiralMatrix[row][column] = loopIndex + 1;  
                      //System.out.println("row : " + row + " column : " + column + " spiralMatrix[row+1][matrix+1] is : "+spiralMatrix[row+1][column+1] + " spiralMatrix[row][column] "+spiralMatrix[row][column]);  
                 }  
            }  
       }  
       return spiralMatrix;  
  }
```

**Sample output : 

1 2 3 4 

12 13 15 5 

11 0 16 6 

10 9 8 7**

Comment: What could an "answer" be here, except for 1. a hint at which point your code is wrong (found through debugging) or 2. a code snippet that creates the solution?

Comment: I expected an answer which would point out the issue where the code is breaking. I tried to debug this code for some hours and was quite helpless. Now, figured out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Finally,

found out the issue. I missed to handle the second layer/next consecutive layers where the previous layers will already be populated with some value. Now, added a check for that. The code is working for happy flow. Now, working on other edge cases.